# Sorting on Items from Lookup Activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline in ADF V-2 that reads the table list from OnPrem SqlServer using a Lookup activity, I then pass those 4 table's list to "for each activity" which is configured to a batch count of 2. This then reads the data for any 2 tables out of my list of 4 and loads them to ADLS. I want to control the order in which its picking up these first 2 tables and so on, probably by sorting the array of items returned by the lookup activity by Priority field. How to achieve sorting on items retrieved from the Lookup activity?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a query in your lookup activity SQL source:

`SELECT * from xxx 
ORDER BY Col1`

Comment: Thanks Atvoid. My query in the lookup does have an order by clause, the output json does show the partition list sorted. But when we pass them to For Each and process in a batch of 4, the partitions are being picked regardless of the order.

Comment: The batch count must be 1, because the ForEach is parallel and order-less.

Answer (score 0):

The Lookup *activity itself* does not apply sorting.  If you want to control the order of a forEach activity, you ***must*** select the Sequential flag in the forEach activity.  Otherwise Data Factory will attempt to run them in parallel.

As @Atvoid suggested, applying `order by` as part of the SQL query in your Lookup activity would be the simplest solution to sort.

Comment: Thanks Martin. My query in the lookup does have an order by clause, the output json does show the partition list sorted. But when we pass them to For Each and process in a batch of 4, the partitions are being picked regardless of the order. Since we would want the partitions to be processes in parallel, we would want the batch count to still work.

Comment: As an example, I made a pipeline that takes a range (1...20) and inside  forEach, uses an append activity.
Running with batch size = 4 gave me [2,1,4,6,5,3,8,10,9,7,13,14,11,17,12,18,16,15,19,20].  This is not in the original order, but roughly ascending.
With parallel execution, there is no guarantee of return order.
Did you want to run something like:
[1...12]->[1,2,3,4][5,6,7,8][9,10,11,12] and then after execution to see
[1,2,4,3,  6,5,7,8,  9,11,10,12]  Where the ordering is random within each of the above subsets, but each subset to be in order ?